# Update content of Google Doc from another Google Doc without creating a new file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have two Google Docs (D1 and D2). I would like to copy the content of D1 into D2. The fileIds of these documents are stored in the database which cannot be modified due to the limitation of the Architecture. Hence, I don't have an option of deleting D2 and creating a copy of D1, because, this will result in a new fileId. I am using Google Drive V3 API (java) to interact with Google Drive.

How can I update the content of Google Doc from another Google Doc without creating a new file?

**Note**: These are Google Docs, not any other format like MS-Word, PDF etc

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no APIs for modifying Google Document yet. This was commented by DaImTo and pinoyyid. So how about creating an API you want? Although I'm not sure whether this is suitable for your situation, how about using GAS and Web Apps to create the API? You can call the Web Apps like API using java. When Web Apps is called from java of local PC, the document from D1 to D2 is copied by GAS. By this, the file ID is not changed, and you can use it as the native Google Document. If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have mentioned in the other answers, Google Drive API does not provide the capability to copy the content of a Google Doc. The only way to achieve this is by using Google Apps Script. Following is the code to do the same:

```
function test() {
  var sourceFileId = 'fileId';
  var targetFileId = 'fileId';

  var sourceDocument = DocumentApp.openById(sourceFileId);
  var targetDocument = DocumentApp.openById(targetFileId);

  var sourceBody = sourceDocument.getBody();
  var targetBody = targetDocument.getBody();

  var sourceHeader = sourceDocument.getHeader();
  var targetHeader = targetDocument.getHeader();

  var sourceFooter = sourceDocument.getFooter();
  var targetFooter = targetDocument.getFooter();

  copyContent(sourceHeader, targetHeader);
  copyContent(sourceFooter, targetFooter);
  copyContent(sourceBody, targetBody);
}

var copyContent = function(source, target) {
  target.clear();

  for(var i = 0; i < source.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = source.getChild(i).copy();

    if (child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      target.appendTable(child);
    } else if (child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      target.appendListItem(child);
    } else if (child.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      target.appendParagraph(child);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** This script does not cover all the sections and element types.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Google drive api is a file directory api only.   You will need to download the file to your system edit the file there and then upload it again.

There is no api that allows for edditing a Google doc on google drive itself.

When you download the file you will be able to choose which format to export it as [Downloading Google Documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) then you can make your changes before uploading again.   [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) Files are in two parts the actual metadata of the file.  Name, description [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) and the actual data of the file.  You will only need to insert the metadata once. Then you can upload the file data when ever you change it this way you will only have one file and not duplicate files just keep the same file id.

## Note App Script

Google app scripts does allow for some editing of Google doc files.   I know this is not what you asked for but it may help you automate your process please see [Google app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs)

Comment: I would like to automate the process. Downloading and editing the file is error prone.

Comment: Unfortunately as developers we are bound by what is possible in the apis that Google gives us.  You can not edit a google doc file on Google drive you need to download it and edit it locally even if you would like to stream line things

Answer (score -1):

In Drive, the content aka media of a file is separate from the metadata of a file.

So, in pseudo code, what you need to do is:-
. Download content of D1
. Use the downloaded content in a content upload to D2.

The file id of D2 remains unchanged.

Comment: Google Drive does not allow to download a Google Doc file. I got the following error - "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files."

Comment: I use download and export interchangeably since ultimately, the content gets downloaded. You are correct insofar there is a distinct export method which performs a format conversion prior to downloading. So replace download with export and off you go.